# Unable to read the "PreventDefault()" and dataTransfer()

Tags: javascript

Even though I am passing the event when calling a function and using this event to call "preventDefault()" and "dataTransfer.setData()", I am not been able to get the result, the chrome is saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined" . Plz help me

```
img.addEventListener("ondragstart",drag(event),false);
canvasA.addEventListener("ondrop",drop(event),false);
canvasA.addEventListener("ondragover",allowDrop(event),false);

function allowDrop(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
}

function drag(e)
{
e.dataTransfer.setData("Text",e.target);
}
```

Comment: Try: remove all `on` from event names, eg "ondrop" --> "drop" and then look at **shennan**'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the event handler, not call it:

Also, `ondragstart` is a property of an element. The event name is most probably just `"dragstart"`, which is what you should use when calling `addEventListener`.

Try this:

```
img.addEventListener("dragstart", drag, false);
canvasA.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
canvasA.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop, false);
```